# Tensorflow - how to unfreeze only specific layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am using a pretrained model like so:

```
base_model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=(150,150,3),
    include_top=False
)
```

Then I freeze all the layers:

```
base_model.trainable = False
```

**Now, I would like to unfreeze only, let's say the most lower layer.**
When I do `base_model.summary()` That's what at the bottom:

[image]

So, let's say I would like to unfreeze `block14_sepconv2` layer.
I do:

```
my_layer = base_model.get_layer('block14_sepconv2')
my_layer.trainable = True
```

And `summary()` still shows, that `Trainable params: 0`
**What am I doing wrong? How to unfreeze only few of the lowest layers?**

Whats intresting, when I firstly do `base_model.trainable = True`, and then I am freezing layers strating from the top, trainable params number actually changes. But its not intuitive for me, and primarly not incomprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to **unfreeze** specific layers. We pick the same model and some layers (e.g. `block14_sepconv2`). The purpose is to **unfreeze** these layers and make the rest of the layers **freeze**.

```
from tensorflow import keras

base_model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=(150,150,3),
    include_top=False
)

# free all layer except the desired layers
# which is in [ ... ]
for layer in base_model.layers:
    if layer.name not in ['block14_sepconv2', 'block13_sepconv1']:
        layer.trainable = False
    
    if layer.trainable:
        print(layer.name)

block14_sepconv2
block13_sepconv1
```

Compute the trainable and non-trainable variables.

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np 

trainable_count = np.sum([K.count_params(w) \
                          for w in base_model.trainable_weights])
non_trainable_count = np.sum([K.count_params(w) \
                              for w in base_model.non_trainable_weights])
print('Total params: {:,}'.format(trainable_count + non_trainable_count))
print('Trainable params: {:,}'.format(trainable_count))
print('Non-trainable params: {:,}'.format(non_trainable_count))
```

```
Total params: 20,861,480
Trainable params: 3,696,088
Non-trainable params: 17,165,392
```

FYI, don't forget to recompile your model (`model.compile(...)`) each time you freeze or unfreeze the layers.

Comment: Ok! Strange, that it doesn't work in reverse: like i did - freezing all and unfreezing specific. Could you please also post a version of a loop, where we accessing and unfreezing a specific number of lower layers? I tried to do this that way: ```base_model.layers[-10:]```

Comment: Actually loop is pretty straightforward, but i dont understand, why when i do [-10:] it shows 15M trainable param, while with [-15:] it shows less - 13M

Comment: I've changed your title from `freeze` word to `unfreeze` because in your question, you mentioned that you want to unfreeze that specific layer.

Comment: About loop, I don't understand your concern propperly, do you want to freeze / unfreeze in range of layers e.g layer 5 to layer 10?

Comment: Its about fine-tuning. I want to fine tune only lets say 5 lower layers, and then check performance with fine-tuned 10 lower layers.

Comment: So, for example you want to unfreeze lastt 5 layers only, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232948/discussion-between-nickname11-and-m-innat).